# puzzling statement on earth history!

Tags: geology, earth-history, evolution

A Geology proffessor recently told me that around 200,000 years ago, when homo sapiens emerged, that *"...all of civilisation can now fit on the width of a single strand of human hair."*

I am perplexed! What did he mean by this?

Comment: Could be a comment on how short a time humans have been around geologically speaking. If you make a timeline of the 4.5 billion year history of the earth, and it’s like 5 feet long, 200,000 years is about one human hair width

Comment: @Ben51 Ah yes, you must be absolutely correct. He was walking 100 meters with each step being 50 million years. Makes perfect sense. Thanks for the clarification!